# What to do about errors like 'setTimeout8387984275464602 is undefined'?

Tags: javascript, error-handling, settimeout

We recently enabled JS error logging on our site, and we're trying to weed out errors that we shouldn't worry about, e.g. ones caused by misbehaving addons that the users have installed.

We get a very large number of errors like `TypeError: setTimeout8387984275464602 is undefined`. The numbers after setTimeout don't seem to be completely random, as we get *hundreds* of errors with the same number.

We aren't doing anything weird to the native setTimeout function.

Has anyone encountered errors like this? Any clue as to why they're happening? Can we safely ignore them?

Comment: Errors are errors, you can ignore them, but you shouldn't. I guess you have a misbehaving `eval()` somewhere in your code, or `window["setTimeout" + random_string()]` should be a callback function. Both would be bad practice. :) But maybe it could be something else.